# How to convert 3 channeled image to 1 channeled image without using cv2.cvtColor()?

Tags: python, opencv, rgb

So, I have been asked to convert a **BGR** image to **GRAYSCALE** using weighted mean of each pixel.

```
img = cv2.imread('..\\Images\\horse.jpg',-1)
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
gray = img.copy()
for x in range(img.shape[1]):
  for y in range(img.shape[0]):
     gray[y][x]= (0.11 * img[y][x][0] + 0.6 * img[y][x][1] + 0.3 * img[y][x][2])



print(gray)
print(gray.shape)
cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

Shape of the resultant image:

```
(404, 640, 3)
```

it should be a single channeled image right?
In result the image shown is GRAYSCALE but still it is a 3 channeled image, can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Change your -1 to 0 or use cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE in your cv2.imread command. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is so simple, this happens because you copied the whole `img` at the beginning which has three channels. You need to copy just one channel like so:

```
gray = img[:, :, 0].copy()
```

Comment: Glad, I could help :)

Comment: @Anwarvic Do you need to copy ? I don't think so... (For use in his code I mean)

Comment: @BenedictWilkinsAI, yeah, you are right. I don't need to copy the whole image and I don't need two `for` loops either. My focus was to solve his/her problem with the minimum number of changes.